# Tensorflow.Js chatbot training

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I create an chatbot using **tensorflow.js**. I have a dict, and all data are word position in this dict, **for example**:

```
dict = {'hello':2, 'how':3, 'are':4, 'you':5, 'i'm':6, 'fine':7},
data_x = [2,3,4,5], data_y = [6,7,0,0]
```

My code:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
const data1 = [[2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0], [11, 0, 0], [12, 0, 0], [13, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0], [15, 0, 0], [16, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [17, 18, 19], [20, 5, 6], [21, 0, 0]]
const data2 = [[2, 22, 0], [7, 0, 0], [23, 0, 0], [8, 24, 0], [25, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0], [26, 27, 28], [9, 0, 0], [29, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [30, 31, 0], [5, 6, 32], [7, 0, 0]]

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

async function train () {
      for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
            await model.fit(tf.tensor(data1[i]), tf.tensor(data2[i]))
      }
}

train ().then(() =>{
      model.predict(tf.tensor([3, 4, 0])).print();
})
```

But loss very big and chatbot say [76,100,2] (i dont have this in dict). How to fix it?